# How can i make an object (for example imageview) appear or disappear smoothly in android ?

Tags: android, visibility

How can I make an object appear or disappear **smoothly**?

Comment: you mean flashing behaviour? show and hide after an interval

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Use [alpha animation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html)

1) To hide, increase alpha to FF.  Then set visibility to `View.GONE`

2) To show, set visibility to `View. VISIBLE` and then decrease alpha from FF to 00.

Example code:

```
AlphaAnimation blinkAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
    blinkAnimation.setDuration(1000); // duration
    blinkAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```